# Positioning of drop down to left

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create 3 - tire drop down menu. I am positioning the third level sub menu to left of parent menu, but the top positions is no aligning properly.

below screen is the result i got.

css code:

```
/* the menu_new_new is the list, you don't need a wrapping div */
#menu_new{
    Text-Align: Left;
    /*width:100%;*/
    background:#194eb1;
   /* height:30px;*/
}

/* only mainmenu_new listitems */
#menu_new > li{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    line-height:35px;
}

/* links in mainmenu_new and both submenu_news */
#menu_new a{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0px 10px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:Left;
}

/* submenu_news of both levels */
#menu_new li ul{
   position: absolute;
   top: 35px;
   left:0;
   min-width:150px;
   background: #194eb1;
  Text-Align: Left;


}
/* submenu text */
#menu_new li ul li{

  Text-Align: Left;
  line-height:20px;
  List-style-type:none;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
/* move the second level submenu_new to the right to don't overlap the parent submenu_new */
#menu_new ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    top:auto;
    left:150px; 
    Z-index: 10;  

}

/* hover effect for submenu_new links */
#menu_new li li a:hover{
   background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

/* hide all submenu_news for default */
#menu_new li ul{
    display: none;
}

/* show a submenu_new if the direct parent listitem is hovered */
#menu_new li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}
```

How to align the top position exactly to parent menu position?

Please refer this for sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/asovbLqd/?

[image: Result screen]

Comment: can you create a demo of code using http://jsfiddle.net/ and share? That will be more helpful!

Comment: I have created the code in fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/asovbLqd/ Please refer to this and help me.

Comment: Find my answer and working fiddle below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Chk URL [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/ErAshu/sfLoeycf/)

```
#menu_new ul ul{
   top:0px;
}
#menu_new li ul li{
   position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Also need to add `position: relative` to `#menu_new li ul li`.

For `#menu_new ul ul`, instead of `top: auto`, use `top: 0`.

Comment: Then all sub menus are positioning at top of main menu. see this: <http://jsfiddle.net/asovbLqd/10/>

Comment: @SandeepReddyK. I guess I overlooked it because the fiddle only had tier 3 menus for the first tier 2 entries. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the Top for all sub menu, you need to provide "`postion:relative` to its parent element"

And to fix the Left extra space you need is to remove the default **Padding** from "`<ul>`" tag

Here is the Fiddle with both issues resolved "**Top position and Left position**":

**http://jsfiddle.net/asovbLqd/14/**

I have just changed the below:

Added `position: relative;` to the parent element of Sub Menu `<ul>`

```
#menu_new li ul li {
    Text-Align: Left;
    line-height:20px;
    List-style-type:none;
    border: 1px solid white;
    position: relative;
}
```

And Removed Padding and margin from `<ul>` tags
    #menu_new ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 150px;
        z-index: 10;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

```
#menu_new li ul {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Then all sub menus are positioning at top of main menu. see this:http://jsfiddle.net/asovbLqd/12/